# Why am I getting a jagged brush when sculpting with dynotopo?

Tags: workflow, sculpting, topology, dynamic-topology

I've created a simple mesh consisting of a cube that has been modelled out into a corner by extrusion:

[image]

I'm now trying to sculpt detail onto it in sculpt mode using dynotopo, however I'm getting different results on different sides of the mesh.

The bottom of the mesh (which was the original cube that I extruded from) sculpts nice and smoothly as expected, however the other side is jagged and distorted which I can't sculpt as nicely. Why is this? The original faces appear to be the same.

[image]

Comment: You didn't apply scale to your object

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This should be an answer.

Comment: An answer it is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didn't apply scale to your object.

In *Object Mode* with your object selected press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply > Scale*

Comment: That's exactly it - could you explain why I need to do this?

Comment: Probably a limitation of the current system. Your object appears short, but is in fact tall and squished down. This causes issues while trying to paint on it, Blender brush can't read its true dimensions causing artifacts as it compensates for scale, that results in squished down strokes.