# What is this anomaly when I'm trying to sculpt and how do I fix it?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

[image]

The mesh derived from a cylinder and I've put Mirror, Bevel and Subsurf modifiers on it before sculpting.

EDIT: Ok, so flood filling seemed to have fixed the weird stretching. But the brushes don't work on the top side of the mesh.. I can sculpt the sides just fine. Note: I've scaled the mesh down on the Z axis but I've applied the scaling.
Here's the project(excuse the messiness, I've been experimenting a bit on that project):

[image]

Comment: Either poor topology, uneven mesh density or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80840/why-am-i-getting-a-jagged-brush-when-sculpting-with-dynotopo/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've been scaling it down on the Z axis a bit, but I've applied the scale. I've also tried flood filling it, but the weirdest thing is: I can't seem to sculpt on the top of the mesh. Sides are working just fine, but the brushes don't work on the top...

Comment: Provide us the .blend here mate. At 1st try to Remove Doubles and check if You dont have **faces inside**.

Comment: Have you made sure to apply all the modifiers? I get similar anomalies when not applying my subdivision.

Comment: yep, applied them all

Answer (score 5):

## Problem Breakdown

As Duarte already assumed, your mesh has uneven density. This is a problem for all sculpting methods, since the algorithms get confused about which edges to subdivide.

However, there is a possibility to fix this by using Dynamic Topology and relative detail.

You also want to use a "sharp brush" Texture in form of a simple white png with a black outline (image below).

[image: sharp brush]

## Fixing the Topology and smoothing the Surface

In Sculpt mode, activate Dyntopo, switch from "Constant Detail" to "Relative Detail", change the Detail Value to 4.0 and activate "Smooth Shading".
While you are here, also **deactivate all settings in the Symetry/Lock section below** (image below).

[image: constant to relative detail]

Then, select the "Clay Strips" Brush, lower its strenght to 0.1 and lock it to "Area Plane".
Under "Texture", add a new texture, load the "sharp brush" texture from above and activate "rake" and "random" (image below).

[image: Brush and Texture Settings]

The setup is now complete and you can start fixing the topology. Sculpt only with a small portion on the handle and the pommel. 
When switching to Edit Mode, your topology should look more or less like this:

[image: Topology in Edit Mode]

Back in Sculpt Mode, switch from "Relative Detail" to "Constant Detail", change the Resolution by using the "Sample" button to sample it from the newly sculpted portion of the mesh.
Next, hit "Detail Flood Fill" and then "Optimize" (image below).

[image: Relative to Constant Detail, Flood Fill and Optimize]

Switch back from "Constant Detail" to "Relative Detail", change the Detail to 8.00, then select the "Smooth Brush" and select the "sharp brush" texture from above.

Turn on Matcap and select preferably a glossy one to highlight distortions. 
Turn on "Rake" and "Random", then start smoothing the whole mesh. Be careful around the sharp edges, turn down the brush strenght to 0.2, if necessary. 
Work your way around the mesh until everything looks smooth (image below).

[image: Smoothing the Mesh]

Your mesh shold now be fixed and you can start to add the details. You might want to play with the Detail settings under Dynamic Topology to get the detail level you want to see in your result.

[image: Ready to add more Details]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time! Second, I've done everything step by step but when I got to the smoothing part, it didn't exactly smooth.. Quite the opposite, it made the surface rough and I still had the problem of brushes not working correctly on the top. When I use the snake hook brush, the result just slopes to the sides, it doesn't go to the Z axis at all. Here's the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H0TsTu_10QnxaBQD8ITPxsZEbxKyheIS